# How can I tell if an aircraft (N-number) is already equipped with an ADS-B transponder?

Tags: ads-b

Is there any database that contains this information?

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27660/how-many-commercial-jetliners-are-equipped-with-ads-b) asked how many aircraft already have one. Here I am asking how can I get *which* contain it.

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for? Do you need  to know the equipage for all aircraft on the US register or only a subset? I.e. all aircraft or only for aircraft that fly over your backyard.

Comment: In the US there's no requirement to register with any authority the type of transponder that's installed. An aircraft owner is free to swap out the transponder without telling anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's onesy twosy, you can try searching flight logs of specific aircraft to see if ADS-B output is recorded.  Here is an example: [track log showing ADS-B returns](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/SKW4917/history/20170607/1255Z/KMKE/KSEA/tracklog)

There is not a free database.  You could purchase a database query of flights that have been tracked by ADS-B.  Depending on the number of aircraft you need, this will affect the cost.  Flight Aware will quote this kind of job.

The FAA database does not provide this information.  It does provide mode-S code information, but that is whether or not the aircraft is so equipped - nothing for ADS-B (yet).

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (for free) is to join the two following databases:

1. Set of all aircrafts that operated in US [from transportation data](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time)
2. (potentially incomplete) set of all operating aircrafts with ADS-B from [adsbexchange](https://www.adsbexchange.com/)